# Compilation error when "#include <gtest/gtest.h>" header file is included

Tags: unit-testing, gcc, compiler-errors, googletest, mingw-w64

when i compile my traingl
e_test.cpp program, i get following errors when gtest.h header file is included in the file.

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\gtest\gtest-message.h:55:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\gtest\gtest-assertion-result.h:46,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\gtest\gtest.h:59,
                 from traingle_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h:1238:8: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   std::mutex mu_;
        ^~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h:1239:8: error: 'condition_variable' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   std::condition_variable cv_;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h: In member function 'void testing::internal::Notification::Notify()':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h:1225:21: error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu_);
                     ^~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h:1225:21: error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h:1225:31: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu_);
```

error messages

[image]

traingle_test.cpp

```
#include "traingle.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
namespace {
TEST (TraingleTest, InvalidSides){
    EXPECT_EQ(-1, TypeOfTraingle(-10, 20, 30));
    EXPECT_EQ(-1, TypeOfTraingle(10, -20, 30));
    EXPECT_EQ(-1, TypeOfTraingle(3, 4, -8));
}
}
```

traingle.cpp

```
#include "traingle.h"
/* Return values
1 for equilateral, 2 for isosceles, 3 for scalan
0 for traingle can't be formed with given sides
-1 if any side value is invalid, say -ve
*/
int TypeOfTraingle(int a, int b, int c){
    if(a<0 || b<0 || c<0)
     return -1;
    if(!(a+b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b))
     return 0;
    else if (a==b && b==c)
     return 2;
    else
     return 3;
}
```

traingle.h

```
#ifndef __TRIANGLE_H
#define __TRIANGLE_H

int TypeOfTraingle(int, int, int);

#endif
```

I have 3 files here traingle.cpp (calculations are done here), traingle_test.cpp (test cases are written) and traingle.h (contains function declaration). the test cases file need to be linked with traingle.cpp and output is how many test cases passed and type of traingle (equilateral, isosceles and scalene triangle) based on test case values(x, y, z) will be displayed as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: Your compiler is too old. Upgrade or use `-std=c++11`.

Comment: should i type this command on same command window which i mentioned above, i typed it as  -std=c++11, but getting bash:command not found, iam doing on windows environment

Comment: This is a command line argument for the compiler. Look it up

Answer (score 0):

Your MinGW GCC (version 6.3.0) is very old.

You will need a MinGW-w64 that was built with POSIX threads support.

A standalone version is available for download from https://winlibs.com/ (separate downloads for 32-bit and 64-bit Windows)

Comment: Hi i followed below procedure for google test set up, could you plz check is it correct or not https://medium.com/swlh/google-test-installation-guide-for-c-in-windows-for-visual-studio-code-2b2e66352456#f91c or if you have any other simpler method plz share

Comment: I build gtest from source as described here: https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/gtest.winlib

Comment: Ok bro. i will check it out

Comment: i installed the tool from the link mentioned still i have some errors after compilation are       C:\Users\kimk274261\Downloads\w64devkit-master\w64devkit-master\zip\w64devkit\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KIMK27~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2Bvjj4.o:traingle_test.:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `TypeOfTraingle(int, int, int)'
C:\Users\kimk274261\Downloads\w64devkit-master\w64devkit-master\zip\w64devkit\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KIMK27~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2Bvjj4.o:traingle_test.:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `testing::Message::Message()'

Comment: there are many such undefiend reference error

Comment: No shouting please (don't type in ALL CAPS).

Comment: Did you build with CMake+Ninja?

Comment: No, not used Cmake+ninja, can you share it?

Comment: See lines 85,89,91,83 in the build recipe I sent you in the link above.
Make sure to replace `$PYDIR` with the path where `python.exe` is located and `$INSTALLPREFIX` with the location where you want to install the result of the build.